# How can I set tab controller as root controller in App Delegate without instantiate (reloading) it?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, push-notification, appdelegate

I am sending notification in my app (firebase) so in didReceiveRemoteNotification, I am directing users to a new place in the app (a view controller in one of the navigation controllers, which are inside of the tab controller).

In the first view in my tab controller, it always checks UserDefaults if the user has been through the Location Services and Push Notifications view controllers (this is where they would accept or decline the permissions). If the user hasn't been through these view controllers (like first time they launch app), it would segue to the appropriate view controller (segue 1 and 2 in image). The problem is that when it segues to Location Services or Push Notifications view controller, the tab bar controller reference in my didReceiveRemoteNotification seems to not be working. That means when I press notification, it does not properly navigate the tab controller if the user was in Location Services or Push Notifications. It DOES work if the user never had to go through Location Services or Push Notifications. That is why I think the root controller is for some reason switching to one of these if the user goes through it.

Plain and simple, I just want my tab bar controller reference to work in my AppDelegate. Why is it only not working when the user goes through Location Services or Push Notifications? Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if(state == .active) {
        // Create local notification
    } else {
        if let businessID = userInfo["business_id"] as? String {
            Globals.notificationBusinessId = Int(businessID)!
        }
        if let businessName = userInfo["business_name"] as? String {
            Globals.notificationBusinessName = "\(businessName)"
        }
        if let itemID = userInfo["item_id"] as? String {
            Globals.notificationItemID = Int(itemID)!
        }
        if let navigationLevel = userInfo["navigation_level"] as? String {
            Globals.notificationNavigationLevel = Int(navigationLevel)!
        }
        Globals.popToBusinessesController = true

        myTabBar.selectedIndex = 1
        myTabBar.selectedIndex = 2
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you tap on notification `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will not be called, this is called only if you receive notification when app is active.
If the app is not running when a remote notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary.

You can check all [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application)

Comment: Yes this part is working for me. When the notification is pressed when the app is closed, it opens the app and navigates to the correct screen. The problem is when in the app, when the user passes through Location Services or Push Notifications, it is messing up the tab bar controller reference. So in this case when the user presses notification, it does nothing. However, if the user didn't go through Location Services and Push Notifications, the tab bar controller seems to work as expected!

Comment: I am just confused as to why when Location Services or Push Notifications is presented to user like when app is first launched, notifications don't work. But any other time, they do. By not work I mean the tab bar is not navigating correctly. It does get into didReceiveRemoteNotification as expected at all times.

Comment: Hmm, well in code it says `if(state == .active)...`, then if user is in the app, nothing happens.

Comment: Even if the app is in the background, it doesn't work. I confirmed that it is getting right before the tab bar controller call but it is not working. It only works when the user has not gone through the Location Services or Push Notifications view controller (like on the second launch of app).

Comment: I just left .active blank for now because I am focusing on when app is in background or closed.

Comment: I think I got it. It seems it was the segues that were messing it up. By switching to present and dismiss instead of segues it seems to be working as expected.